# texture2D splitting in XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I want to make a puzzle game in XNA where I take a picture and divide it into several parts and the user has to get all the parts back in the right order. The thing is I am new to XNA and WP programming and I have googled a lot and still I can't find any good links that help me with what I am trying to do. I just want to know how can I split the texture into different parts. Could anyone help me by providing links if they have them? Or guide me as to how this can be done?
Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to split the pictures into squares or are you wanting to do puzzle shaped pieces?

Comment: then the answer below by Msonic is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want square pieces, you can have multiple pieces with the same image (full puzzle). If you edit the "source" parameter when you draw your puzzle pieces, you can render only a part of the image, thus making different pieces.

Comment: See [the MSDN page for the Draw Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196420(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx) for more details

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the green checkmark below the answer score. Glad to be of help!